# Laptop battery problem 

Tags: windows, battery, charging

I left my HP 625 laptop yesterday on standby at 7% battery - I opened it today and the battery is full.

I waited until it got to around 90% then it died. I left it plugged in until the light showed it is full again (about 10 minutes later) and then removed the cord and battery. It still shows as full.

How can I fix this? It's brand new, bought a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

Brand new and a month old aren't exactly the same thing.  Laptop batteries, specifically the lithium ion variety sometimes fail for no reason at all.  Normally you can fix batteries with memory issues by completely discharging them to 0 and then recharging them, but in your case, your battery is discharging too fast, and then recharging too fast.  Best thing I can tell you is to contact the manufacturer for a replacement.

Comment: No, I would try the complete discharge/recharge first if there's a built-in manufacturer utility for a battery gauge reset.  It's possible the top end of the gauge is very miscalibrated so it's only charging a very small amount and then stopping, and is at least worth a try before you call it quits.

Comment: @Shinrai That's true, but I assumed from their statement of the laptop dying at 90% that it's already beyond resuscitation, since they can't seem to discharge it beyond 90%.

Comment: Right, hence my suggesting a manufacturer utility (they often bury this in the power management software they bundle.)  Obviously OP won't have much luck trying to do it by hand.